# What happened to the right/control + mouse click option to “Get Album Artwork” in iTunes 12.4?

Tags: itunes, album-art

I’m on Mac OS X 10.11.5 (El Capitan) and just upgraded to iTunes 12.4 and if I right/control + mouse click on a track I no longer see “Get Album Artwork” in the list of options. I am 100% positive this used to be the case in earlier (12.3 and lower) versions of iTunes. What gives?

[image: Screenshot showing the right/control + mouse click menu.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is a bug or feature or a sign of “things to come” (i.e.: Apple no longer caring about locally stored and downloaded music) but the option to “Get Album Artwork” is now hidden in the menu area, “File -> Library -> Get Album Artwork.”

[image: Showing the “File -> Library -> Get Album Artwork.”]

But it gets weirder—which is why this is unclear if this is a bug or a feature—but this quirk where “Get Album Artwork” doesn’t show up is only when doing list views of tracks. But if you switch to album view, lo and behold you get to see “Get Album Artwork” again when you right/control + mouse click a full album.

[image: “Get Album Artwork” shows up in album view.]

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the Album name/icon and get access to "Get Album Artwork".

[image: Get Album Artwork]